# Let T1 ⊂ T2 be two topologies on X. For a subset A⊂X, compare the closures of A according to T1 and T2.

Tags: general-topology

Let T1 ⊂ T2 be two topologies on X. For a subset A⊂X, compare the closures of A according to T1 and T2.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please add LaTeX formatting to your question and include what you have attempted.

Comment: The closure of any set in any topology is always closed (the closeure of a set is defined as the smallest closed set that contain $A$). Nevertheless, the closure of $A$ may be different in $(X,T_1)$ and in $(X,T_2)$. @BenGrossmann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any set that is closed with respect to $T_1$ must also be closed with respect to $T_2$. However, the closure is the "smallest" closed set containing $A$. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{cl}_{T_1}(A) \supseteq  \operatorname{cl}_{T_2}(A),
$$
where $\operatorname{cl}_{T}(A)$ denotes the closure of $A$ with respect to the topology $T$.